# How to share plugins section across gradle projects in different repositories

Tags: java, gradle

How to share plugins section across few separate spring boot based gradle projects in different repositories

```
plugins {
    id 'checkstyle'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'idea'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'pmd'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can organize the build logic into reusable plugins, and share these plugins among your modules. Here is the complete sample in the official documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html.